# I want Javascript which gets the file input and save it to local path

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want Javascript which gets the file input and save it to local path

```
<input type="file" name="attachment1" id="attachment1" style="width:500;">

<script>

//Javascript--variable to assign the above file and its name
//Then save it to local path(some where in C drive)

</script>
```

Comment: javascript can't manipulate the filesystem directly, unless you use the filesystem API which is non-standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is a language that, usually, runs on your local machine. Therefore you are sending a potential thread to the pc your code runs on, every time you send that pc some JavaScript.

In order to prevent abuse, computers are protected from doing harmfull stuff like automatically download virusses and store them somewhere on your C drive.

If you want to save it on the server however, have a look into Node.js.

Comment: thanks for information...could you please share the information on Node.js

Comment: Node.js is a back-end engine like PHP, but instead of PHP it works with Javascript at the back-end. Have a look at some youtube tutorials if you want to know what and why, or have a look at questions posted on stackoverflow. One very good tutorial is the node tutorial from thenewboston on youtube. That explains JS and Node together.